# Changing multiple div locations in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting to change 5 div's left/top values using the jquery .each function. Currently, the divs spawn in on top of each other then are not affected by the jquery, the same is happening in this snippet. What do i have to change to make the divs move to a random location on the screen.

```js
$(function() {
  var docHeight = $(window).height(),
    docWidth = $(window).width(),
    $div = $('.randomSpawn'),
    divWidth = $div.width(),
    divHeight = $div.height(),
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
  $div.each(function() {
    $(this).css("left", "Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax )");
    $(this).css("top", "Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )");
  });
});
```

```css
.randomSpawn {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="randomSpawn"></div>
<div id="2" class="randomSpawn"></div>
<div id="3" class="randomSpawn"></div>
<div id="4" class="randomSpawn"></div>
<div id="5" class="randomSpawn"></div>
```

Comment: You are putting the expression as a string in the css method.

Comment: @Jai What would the correct notation be?

Comment: See the answer posted @CianNoonan.

Comment: Aren't you getting the height of a list of divs and trying to assign it as a number as well? It seems to be using $div interchangeably as a single div and a list of divs.

Comment: @Dhunt `.width()` and `.height()` on a list of elements get the data for only the first, but will set for all.

Comment: @Dhunt The height of the divs is uniform, so it shouldn't matter?

Comment: @Scimonster thanks. I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code was in a string. You need it to be normal JS. ;)

```
    $(this).css("left", Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ));
    $(this).css("top", Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ));
```

```js
$(function() {
  var docHeight = $(window).height(),
    docWidth = $(window).width(),
    $div = $('.randomSpawn'),
    divWidth = $div.width(),
    divHeight = $div.height(),
    heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
    widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
  $div.each(function() {
    $(this).css("left", Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ));
    $(this).css("top", Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ));
  });
});
```

```css
.randomSpawn {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="randomSpawn"></div>
<div id="2" class="randomSpawn"></div>
<div id="3" class="randomSpawn"></div>
<div id="4" class="randomSpawn"></div>
<div id="5" class="randomSpawn"></div>
```